# Rails find unused plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

You know it, a Rails project is growing for years, many developers comes, many developers go...

Now it's your turn, You are a newcommer in the company and you are sitting for the "shiny" Rails app source code.

You task is to remove all plugins that clutters the source and are not used anymore.

How will you find them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at each plugin's source code (usually lives in /lib of the plugin or gem folder).

Most of them only define a handful of methods that you are supposed to call in your application code. Search your project directory for all of these method names to see if they are called anywhere.

For example: you have acts_as_ferret plugin, search your codebase for the words "acts_as_ferret".

If you have delayed_job, search for "delay", "send_later", or "handle_asynchronously".

Sure it will take some time, but removing dependencies isn't something you want to do haphazardly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any tests on that rails app you could use rcov to see how much test coverage on the project, if its a good amount of coverage then remove one of the plugins, run the test suite and see if anything fails.